# What weights for weighted Total Least Square (TLS) regression?

Tags: measurement-error, weighted-regression, total-least-squares

I have a dataset with known errors in both the X and Y and want to perform a simple linear regression. From reading other posts, it seems I want to TLS over OLS due to the presence of error in both variables. However, the error is no constant, so I also want to weight measurements.

It seems that weighting with the inverse of the variance is common in weighted OLS. Could I weight with the inverse of the sum of X and Y variance for my TLS regression?

Comment: So the standard weighting procedure when you have errors in both uses a weighted sum of the inverses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

Comment: Great thanks! Should have checked Wikipedia first I guess